# Formatting a CHANGES text file as HTML

Tags: beginner, html, regex, formatting, go

I have a function which is used to convert text (a CHANGES file) into HTML for reading. The function is essentially line-based: if the line is of this type, do this thing; if some other type, do that thing; etc. Further logic needs to be added before the fallback

```
b.WriteString("<p>" + line + "</p>\n")
```

but I wanted to better organize my code before adding the more complex logic.

As written the code looks like a nightmare to me -- there has to be some better, more idiomatic way to write this. I'm new enough to Go that I'm not sure what the best way forward is.

```
var h3Regex = regexp.MustCompile("^Done for version ([1-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9]) \\(released ([0-9/-]+)\\):$")
var h4Regex = regexp.MustCompile("^  (Fixed|Added|Changed|Removed)$")
var variable = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\\(\\))?"
var stuff = "^  (?:[A-Z]+ )?[0-9]+- GP functions? (" + variable + "(?:, ?" + variable + ")*)$"
var GPRegex = regexp.MustCompile(stuff)

func layout(text string) string {
    lines := strings.Split(html.EscapeString(text), "\n")
    var b bytes.Buffer
    for _, line := range lines {
        match := h3Regex.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(match) > 0 {
            b.WriteString("<h3>Version " + match[1] + ", released " + match[2] + "</h3>\n")
            continue
        }
        match = h4Regex.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(match) > 0 {
            b.WriteString("<h4>" + match[1] + "</h4>\n")
            continue
        }
        match = GPRegex.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(match) > 0 {
            funcs := strings.Split(match[1], ",")
            if len(funcs) > 1 {
                b.WriteString("<p>GP functions ")
            } else {
                b.WriteString("<p>GP function ")
            }
            for idx, f := range funcs {
                if idx > 0 {
                    b.WriteString(", ")
                }
                b.WriteString(`<code class="GP">` + f + `</code>`)
            }
            b.WriteString("</p>\n")
            continue
        }
        b.WriteString("<p>" + line + "</p>\n")
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

Comment: Could you include an excerpt of the input file?

Comment: @200_success Essentially it is http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pari.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package from standard library. It will help you a lot in separating parsing code and HTML generation. Also it will escape all input by default.

---

Some other notes:

- It is handy to use `` ` `` instead of `"` when writing regular expressions with lots of escapes.
- `GPRegex` variable [will be exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers). Should it be?
- Kudos for using `bytes.Buffer` and not concating strings by hand (: